# How to extract the shape of MovieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

We have a flash application that we are planning on converting to javascript. It's a pretty simple map application with an image as the background and a bunch of simple polygon movie clips that represent destinations on the map.

I would like to iterate through each movie clip and extract the shape into an array of x,y points to redraw the polygon using an external javascript function.

Is this possible with actionscript?

Comment: See Amarghosh's comment [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836758/flash-how-to-read-data-from-shape-graphics-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to export the shape coordinates at author time, you can do try the JSFL script recommented by @strille or [this one](http://ericlin2.tripod.com/bugwire/bugwiret.html) or export transparent images (if that's not too limiting for your application).

If you need to export the shapes at runtime, you can use the awesome [as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf) library to decompile the swf and export the shapes. Have a look at the [ShapeExport wiki](https://github.com/claus/as3swf/wiki/Shape-Export) as there are couple of handy exporters for js like **JSCanvasShapeExporter** and the more generic **JSONShapeExporter**

Answer (score 0):

Flash Player 11.6 introduced [readGraphicsData()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#readGraphicsData%28%29) which does exactly what you ask for.

If you need to target an earlier version, then there's no simple way to read shape coordinates from a display object with ActionScript at runtime unfortunately.

If you just want to extract the shape coordinates once someone has written a [jsfl script for Flash CS3](http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=463) which looks like it might be able to help you out.

Comment: This looks great, exactly what I am looking for. In the fla our shapes are exported as MovieClips - any idea how to reference the root Shape object using jsfl?

Comment: Also, I don't necessarily need to read the shape coordinates at Runtime. We do have access to the fla files so hopefully we can read them from there somehow.

Comment: Even though it's a little beside the point, I'm going disagree with half this answer. You could build some methods in flash that would return the desired information that you can expose to javascript via ExternalInterface. This would allow you to get at the info at runtime.

Comment: Bobrot, you're absolutely right and I have edited the answer to be less definitive. What I meant was that there's no built in API for doing it in AS. I should have mentioned it could be done by reading and parsing the swf.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways you can read the coordinates from an SWF. For instance, I've written a parser in PHP ([link](http://code.google.com/p/flaczki/source/browse/trunk/flaczki/SWFParser.php)). Getting the data doesn't help though, as it turns out. The Flash painting model is different enough from the HTML5 one enough to make transfer exceeding difficult. The main obstacle I discovered is that in Flash, a path can be filled with two fill styles: one for area enclosed by the path, the other for enclosed area considered to be "outside" by the even-odd rule (e.g. the pentagon in the middle of a star). Since the HTML5 canvas let you specify only one fill style, you can't redraw shapes from Flash accurately. I was trying to create a tool that extract shapes as SVG and was getting a lot of gap and holes in the result.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to read coordinates from the SWF, I have access to the fla file and each shape is defined in my library and exported as a movieclip

Comment: The shapes are stored in the same way in FLA. There're still fillStyle0 and fillStyle1. Basically, you can get the paths but you won't be able to fill them correctly. It's not something that you can easily do. I would check out Flash CS6's export to HTML5 option. That should probably yield data set that's usable.