# Save/Load MovieClip Air Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

In AS3 AIR for Android Application I'm developing, the user can build some drawing using shapes and graphics properties. It must to possibility to user save its drawing in its `File.applicationStorageDirectory` and then, load its drawing again, with properties of draw intact.
Look at the following code:

This is class that represent the drawer:

```
public class Background extends Sprite {
    public var shape:Shape;
    public function Background(){
        this.shape = new Shape();
        shape.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        shape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        shape.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(shape);
    }
}
```

Outside, into main: `public var bg:Background;`

So, when I load some swf externally, I can save/load it without any problem, cause I have its ByteArrays into loader class.

But how can I save a DisplayObject built at runtime?
Something like this:

```
bg = new Background();

try{
            bytes = new ByteArray();
            file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("test/some.swf");
            fileStream = new FileStream();
            fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
            fileStream.writeBytes(bytes) // -----HERE, I DO NOT HAVE bg bytes,
            fileStream.close();

        } catch (e:IOError){
            fileStream.close();
        }
```

I have tried using writeObject() method, it saves normally, but when I try to load it, throws a exception: Unknow file format.

How can I do that? How can I extract bg bytes, or save it any way? Obviously, I wanna retrieve it again, with all its properties intact.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flash : How to read data from shape/graphics object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836758/flash-how-to-read-data-from-shape-graphics-object)

Comment: You want to save the actions taken by the user.  Not try to save and interpret the drawing.  So when user "draws" a square, save the info then.  This opens your app up to having a history, recreate the drawing actions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialisation of DisplayObjects was not possible for a long time and failed silently.

You can either do the serialisation yourself, by recording what the user does, then save that record of the actions instead of the result.
(The command pattern comes to mind.)

Or, this:
http://www.bytearray.org/?p=4893

Also, take a look at this question:
[How to read data from shape/graphics object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836758/flash-how-to-read-data-from-shape-graphics-object)

Comment: Thank you for your time. Do you mean I should record the user action and then redraw based in that actions?

Comment: Yes, that would be a possible solution, because you can define a way to serialize those actions. But with the option of readGraphicsData() as seen in the other question I linked to) you can also read the data and serialize that. Using the built in function is less work, but the command pattern (record actions and execute them) gives you more flexibility. Example: you can easily create an "undo last action" functionality by simply removing the last action from the list of all actions. Your choice depends on what else you want to do in your application.

Comment: I got it. Certainly I'll use Command pattern to do that. Just one more question, how can I serialize the vector of action? I do not know too.

Comment: Each action is an object that's not a DisplayObject, therefore you should be able to serialize it with writeObject(). The basic calls to the drawing API are already available as classes, check this link:http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS749610B4-4709-4f75-BBA0-650BF52623CA.html#WS2f73111e7a180bd0-3ecdc7ad13c55f37d54-8000 These are the same you'd get from readGraphicsData(). All you have to do to create your "actions" is to translate your function calls to these classes. For pure serialisation purposes, just reading and writing them is sufficient.

Comment: YES! So I can serialize any type of class unless DisplayObject.
Just to finalize, I can, for instance, save the data that came from readGraphicsData entirely, cause GraphicsData is subclasse of Object and not of DisplayObject. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are objects other than DisplayObjects that cannot be serialized natively. But yes, what your receive from readGraphicsData() should be serializable. After all, that's probably the reason why they introduced this method.